# Script task Issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

I have a script task that picks up an excel file and references `Microsoft.office.interop.excel` which is all fine. It runs fine on my workstation but when I deploy this to server it errors.

> Script Task:Error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with
> CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the
> following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I have checked that the proxy account has access to the excel location.  I have also made sure the package is running in 32Bit mode on the server and in my debug environment, which, as I say works fine in debug but as soon as I deploy to server it fails.  I have also checked to make sure that Microsoft.office.interop.excel exists in the GAC and is the same version.

I am at a loss as to what the problem here is....  Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If I recall correctly, interop is an interface to COM. Pretty sure you actually need excel installed on the server to provide the COM parts

Comment: thank @Nick.McDermaid but is tere any another option without installing excel on that server.

Comment: It depends what your script is doing. If you are working with xlsx files you can use various libraries that work with those file directly, and not through excel. You'd need to rewrite whatever you are doing though. Google seems to consistently return this library. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.4.1 What are you doing in your script? is it complex? You would need to install that library on the server but that is generally much more acceptable to install on a server than excel

Comment: i am trying to get the cell address based on cell value